# When using std set find, the program will not compile

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a string in a std::set, but when using std::set::find, it produces a very long error that I do not understand. I can access the set from the program, so that is not the issue.

When I just run the find, it works fine, but when I use it in anything, like setting it to a variable or trying to output it, the compiler freaks out. I see that the errors are coming from a c++ 7 folder, but this is supposed to be c++11, so I don't know.

Here is where I am trying to use the command:

```
int interperet() {
  cout << ">"; 
  if (!cin.getline(input,sizeof(input))) {
    cout << "ErrCode 1: Could not get input" << endl;
  }

  cout << commands.find("help cmmds.cpp");


  return 0;
}
```

Here is the set:

```
set<string> commands = {
  "help cmmds.cpp"
};
```

Here is a pastebin of the compiler output:
https://pastebin.com/U6dfy8Lq

Am I correct in saying that the error claims that it cannot convert `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should consult the reference to see what `find` actually returns: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find

Comment: Please see how to [ask] with a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

The type returned by `std::set<T>::find()` is an `Iterator`.

You can not pass `Iterators` to output streams (generally speaking). But you can de-reference the iterator to get a reference to `T` and if this is streamable via `operator<<` then it will print.

```
auto find = commands.find("X");
std::cout << (*find) << "\n;
              ^  // de-reference the iterator.
```

Now don't write the code like I have done above. The problem here is that find may fail. If the find fails it returns the `end()` iterator for the container. It is undefined behavior to de-reference the `end()` iterator so you must really check for this.

```
auto find = commands.find("X");
if (find != commands.end()) {
    std::cout << (*find) << "\n;
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this makes total sense. For some reason I though find would return the string.

Answer (score 1):

Find returns an object of type Container::iterator

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/

Generally those objects don't support print/streaming methods.

What you probably want to know is whether it was found, so you could stream `(commands.find("help cmmds.cpp") != commands.end())` instead.

Comment: How should the OP modify their source, `cout << commands.find("help cmmds.cpp");` to (1) check if found and (2) if found print the string found? Please update your answer so as to make it more complete and usable.

Comment: Well the string found would be the string input, as it is a simple set, so the only useful piece of information is whether the item was found, so the only thing you can print is the test for was it found.

Comment: What good is an iterator if it can't provide the value being looked for? The iterator should provide a way to access the data found if it is found. `std::cout << ' ' << *it;` from your link.

Comment: I would agree if it was a map or a part-indexed set with a custom ordering method. As it stands, all this is useful for is to tell you if it was found, and perhaps you could iterate from there to the end. If I were testing upper_bound or lower_bound I would also agree with you. Nothing against the OP, it is a very simple example, but has very little utility beyond telling you the exact string you asked for has or has not been found.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in saying that the error claims that it cannot convert std::__cxx11::basic_string to std::__cxx11::basic_string?

No. That would not be accurate.

The error claims that it cannot convert `std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::iterator` to any of the candidates of overload set for `operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, ....`.

Let us call that type `set::iterator` for conciseness. That is what `set::find` returns and what you've attempted to insert into the output stream.

---

You'll need to decide what you inteded by your attempt to insert an iterator into the output stream.

If your intention is to print whether a value exists in the set, you can use this instead:

```
// only since C++20
cout << commands.contains("help cmmds.cpp");
// pre C++20
cout << commands.find("help cmmds.cpp") != commands.end();
```

If your intention is to print the string, you could use:

```
const char* str = "help cmmds.cpp";
if (commands.contains(str))
    cout << str;
```

Or you could indirect through the returned iterator. But you must first check whether it was found:

```
auto it = commands.find("help cmmds.cpp");
if (it != commands.end())
    std::cout << *it;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I never even thought to use contains.

Comment: @lukeisme well, `contains`  doesn't yet exist in the official standard, since it will be introduced in the upcoming C++20 standard. But it it already supported by relatively new standard library implementations.

Comment: Oh ok. The program I'm using only supports c++11, so I don't think that work.